# Understanding induction proof with inequalities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm having a hard time proving inequalities with induction proofs. Is there a pattern involved in proving inequalities when it comes to induction? For example:

Prove ( for any integer $n>4$ ):

$$2^n > n^2 \\ $$

Well, the skipping ahead to the iduction portion, here's what I've got so far:

let $n=k$, then $2^{k+1} > (k+1)^2 $.

Starting with the **LHS**

$$\begin{align}     \\  2^{k+1}=2\cdot2^k  \\  > 2\cdot k^2  \end{align}$$

And that 's where it ends for me. What would be the next step, and what suggestions might you give for future proofs like this? Do we always need to prove that the left hand side is equal to the other?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Do we always need to prove that the left hand side is equal to the other?" It seems that is not what we're doing even in this case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working off Eric's answer/approach:

Let P(n) be the statement that $2^n \gt n^2$.

**Basis step: (n=5)** $2^5\gt 5^2 $ which is true.

**Inductive step:** We assume the inductive hypothesis that $P(k)$ is true for an arbitrary integer $k\ge5$.

$$ 2^{k} \gt k^2 \text{ (IH)}$$

Our goal is to show that P(k+1) is true. Let's multiply each side by two:

$$ 2*2^{k}>2(k)^2 $$

$$ 2^{k+1}>2k^2 $$

If this statement is true, then $2k^2$ $\ge$ $(k+1)^2$ must also be true when $k\ge5$:
$$ 2k^{2}\ge(k+1)^2 $$
$$ 2k^{2} \ge k^2+2k+1$$
$$k^2\ge2k+1$$

And it is. Therefore $\forall{_{k\ge5}}P(k) \implies P(k+1)$ and $\forall{_{n\ge5}}P(n)$ follows by induction.

Comment: Sorry for asking almost a year late, but how come $k^2 \geq 2k +1$ holds for every $k\geq 5$?, do I need to prove that also by induction?, or can I just replace 5 and see if it holds?

Comment: @Miguelgondu It should be obvious when you graph $k^2$ and $2k+1$ that $k^2 \ge 2k+1$ will hold true for all values of $k \ge 2.42$. You are correct though, this does not formally prove anything. 

The statement $k^2 \ge 2k+1$ really needs to be proved by induction for my answer to be valid. This link may be a useful reference for doing so: http://cpsc.ualr.edu/srini/DM/chapters/examples/ex2.3.2.html

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $2^n > n^2$. Then $2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n > 2n^2$. We are done if we can show that $2n^2>(n+1)^2$ for $n>4$. This is true iff $n^2 > 2n + 1$, which it is for $n>4$. (One way to prove this might be to note that the derivative of $x^2-2x-1$ is positive for $x\geq 4$, therefore it is increasing, and it takes a positive value at 4.)

Comment: Okay, where did $2n^2 > (n+1)^2 $ come from? I think this is where I got confused when the professor showed it...

Comment: @Dimitri In the second sentence I noted that **if** we can show that $2n^2 > (n+1)^2$, then we are done. In the third sentence, I said that an equivalent condition is $n^2>2n+1$. Then I noted that this is true.

Comment: @EricAuld I understand that if we can show that $2n^2 > (n+1)^2$, then we're done. But what I was implying was, how do we know that we need to show that?